# WWWRoot folders are not accessible

Tags: css, .net, .net-core

I'm using .net core mvc, and I just started a new project. I have this code in a stylesheet in the css folder inside the wwwroot folder

[image]

[image: The location of the image I want to access]

However, when I try to run the code the image is not being fetched throwing a 404 error and it shows that its seeking for the images folder within the css folder, so how do I get past this ? I tried using `../images/slider/2.jpg` but it still is not being fetched

EDIT: Fixed it, the problem was the browser cached the stylesheet

Comment: Have you tried just `images/slider/2.jpg` ?

Comment: @Nikita Chayka again it just searches inside the css folder